# Query for the latest 3 weeks data in Snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In a Snowflake query, I will like to query for the latest 3 weeks of data based on a column that has the WorkWeek number with the data type as Number (not timestamp).

My Database looks like this:

| WorkWeek | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202234 | ... | ... |
| 202233 | ... | ... |
| 202233 | ... | ... |
| 202232 | ... | ... |
| 202232 | ... | ... |

What I want (latest 3 Workweeks data):

| WorkWeek | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202235 | ... | ... |
| 202234 | ... | ... |
| 202233 | ... | ... |
| 202233 | ... | ... |

What I am using so far the code is a pretty manual way of catching the latest 3 weeks data, I will like the new code to be able to catch the latest 3 weeks data as a new week rolls into the db:

```
Select *
From DB
where WorkWeek in ('202235','202234','202233')
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualify with Dense Rank is what you need:

```
select column1 as WorkWeek, column2 as SomeData from values
   (202235,'a')
    ,(202235,'b')
    ,(202235,'c')
    ,(202234,'d')
    ,(202233,'e')
    ,(202233,'f')
    ,(202232,'g')
    ,(202232,'h')
qualify dense_rank() over (order by WorkWeek desc) <= 3;
```